Fixing PHP Extension Errors: Unable to Load mysqli and pdo_mysql on Ubuntu
I have to setup php with codeigniter without xampp server in ubunto but I am facing a lot of problem or it is not setup sometimes it starts giving warning in php version and sometimes error is shown in mysqli can anyone suggest me the correct.
took a lot of help from Chatgapt and also took help from Google but I am not able to do this, I am very fond of this setup.
